# CustomUser created through Django Admin cannot login (Django Rest Framework)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I created a register/login system through DRF by overriding dj_rest_auth

If registering an user with Postman, by firing on the endpoint, that user can be used for login through endpoint

However, if creating an user through *Django Admin*, that user cannot be used for login through endpoint, and notably, if seen through Django Admin, **the password is not hashed**

How to handle this?

**serializers.py**

```
class CustomLoginSerializer(LoginSerializer):

    def validate_auth_user_status(self, user):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        if not request.data.get('role'):
            msg = 'Role is missing from the payload.'
            raise exceptions.ValidationError(msg)
        if not user.groups.filter(name=request.data.get('role')).exists():
            msg = 'Invalid role for the user.'
            raise exceptions.ValidationError(msg)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        pass    # Empty because the function is not needed
                # but Pylint demanded to implement it anyway

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        pass    # Empty because the function is not needed
                # but Pylint demanded to implement it anyway


class CustomRegisterSerializer(RegisterSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()

    def get_cleaned_data(self):
        super().get_cleaned_data()
        return {
            'email': self.validated_data.get('email', ''),
            'password1': self.validated_data.get('password1', ''),
            'name': self.validated_data.get('name', '')
        }

    def create(self, validated_data):
        pass        # Empty because the function is not needed
                # but Pylint demanded to implement it anyway

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        pass    # Empty because the function is not needed
                # but Pylint demanded to implement it anyway

    def save(self, request):
        user = super().save(request)
        user.name = self.get_cleaned_data().get('name')
        user.save()
        client_role, _created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='client')
        user.groups.add(client_role)
        return user
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('auth/registration/', include('dj_rest_auth.registration.urls')),
    path('auth/', include('dj_rest_auth.urls')),
    path('auth/user-login/', CustomLoginView.as_view(), name='custom_user_login'),
    path('auth/google/', GoogleView.as_view(), name='google'),
]
```

**models.py**

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    diet_profile = models.OneToOneField(
        DietProfile,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=False,
        related_name="user",
        blank=True, null=True
    )
    nutritionist = models.ForeignKey(
        Nutritionist,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="clients",
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.email)
```

EDIT:
adding custom user manager and admin.py

**manager.py**

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """
    Custom user model manager where email is the unique identifiers
    for authentication instead of usernames.
    """
    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('The Email must be set'))
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        client_role, _created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='client')
        user.groups.add(client_role)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password.
        """
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_staff=True.'))
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.'))
        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .models import CustomUser

admin.site.register(CustomUser)
```

Comment: Add the `CustomUserManager()`, as well as admin.py.

Comment: added the CustomUserManager alongside admin.py

Comment: Two cents idea : [RegisterSerializer](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/blob/master/rest_auth/registration/serializers.py#L166) dont handle any password hashing. You could try to call set_password() in `CustomRegisterSerializer.save()`